# Get right path to resx

Tags: c#, path, sitemap, resx

I need to print a second menu (every things is nice with it), this menu use a different sitemap and resx.

My problem is that I can't print the title. The element in my menu is the right one, but title and definition are empty.

Faq.SiteMap :

```
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="~/App_Pages/FAQ/Test.aspx" title="$Resources:FAQ,FAQTest"  description="$Resources:FAQ,FAQTestDescription">
      <siteMapNode url="~/App_Pages/FAQ/Test/Testdoc.pdf" title="$Resources:FAQ,FAQTestDoc"  description="$Resources:FAQ,FAQTestDocDescription" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

My project is like this :

```
~/MySite
   /App_GlobalResources/FAQ.resx    
   /App_Page/FAQ
      /faq.aspx
      /faq.sitemap
```

Do I need to put my resx in the same directory ? Are they an other way to define the path in the sitemap ?

EDIT : I found the problem, I've forgot enableLocalisation

```
<siteMap enableLocalization="true" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I've forgot enableLocalisation

```
<siteMap enableLocalization="true" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
```